# vb.net SQL Server DB retrieving all results based on Date Range using 2 DateTime Picker

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datetime

I'm writing a vb.net programming that could retrieve all relevant data from SQL server DB based on the date range like eg. 3 October 2016 to 7 October 2016. I had two DateTime pickers to act as "Date From" and "Date To" respectively and so far the below code was able to retrieve the data based on what I had set on both of my DateTime picker.

```
Dim dFrom As DateTime = dtDateFrom.Value
Dim dTo As DateTime = dtDateTo.Value.AddDays(1)
Dim queryIncident As String

dgvGen.Columns.Clear()
cn.Open()
queryIncident = "SELECT * FROM tblIncidentTrackingMod WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN '" & Format(dFrom, "dd-MM-yyyy") & "' AND '" & Format(dTo, "dd-MM-yyyy") & "'"
da = New SqlDataAdapter(queryIncident, cn)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "dsGenerate")
dgvGen.DataSource = ds.Tables("dsGenerate")
dgvGen.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
cn.Close()
```

Now here's the issue. ***When I attempted to select a date range based on particular weeks that will cross over to a new month like eg. "28 Nov 2016 to 2 Dec 2016", the program could not retrieve any of the related data based on that date range. Clearly I have data containing these dates in SQL server DB but it's not appearing.*** I had looked up for solutions but couldn't any, so I was hoping to find a solution here. Thanks!

Comment: What is the datatype of `TimeStamp` in your database? is it in `DateTime`?

Comment: If you truly do have to convert your dates to strings - which you really *should not do* - then make it into the yyyy-MM-dd format to be sure that you do not get locale conflicts

Comment: @CrushSundae Sundae It's varchar(60) on my DB

Comment: I recommend you to change it from `varchar` to `datetime` since you are expecting a **date** comparison with `BETWEEN`, as of now it is compared as `varchars` not as `date`. It is also a good practice to use table fields matching with their respective **datatype**. By the way, welcome to the site!

Comment: storing dates in a varchar field = asking for troubles. At least store it in an universal format like yyyyMMdd but better would be to fix that first and alter it to a date format

Comment: Icic.. Thanks for the advice. I will try it out on a while. And thanks! =)

Comment: I had tried your suggestions, and while I truly appreciate the suggestions given, I'm still having the same issue.I re-edited my question again for better clarifications as the issue seems to be affecting those particular weeks that will cross over to a new month while the rest of the weeks that were in the same month had no issue. =)

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters in your sql command. No need to open the connection. SqlDataAdapter will automatically do this when you call its Fill method.

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tblIncidentTrackingMod WHERE TimeStamp BETWEEN @from AND @to"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@from", dFrom)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@to", dTo)

da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "dsGenerate")    
dgvGen.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: It works on the first try, but when I attempt to run again with a new date range it gave me an error that states 'variable "@from" is already declared' message.

Comment: Issue a cmd.ClearParameters before adding them.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Dim MLD As New Globalization.GregorianCalendar

   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            T1.Value = DateAndTime.Now
      Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub


   Private Sub T1_ValueChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles T1.ValueChanged
        ChangeDD1()
    End Sub

  Private Sub ChangeDD1()
        Try
            Dim ADay, AMonth As String
            ADay = MLD.GetDayOfMonth(T1.Value)
            AMonth = MLD.GetMonth(T1.Value)
            If ADay.Length = 1 Then
                ADay = "0" & ADay
            End If
            If AMonth.Length = 1 Then
                AMonth = "0" & AMonth
            End If
            TD1.Text = ADay & AMonth & MLD.GetYear(T1.Value)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

and Save TD1.Text as string in your database